# How to place all text from a file into the search pattern of grep?

Tags: bash, grep

I am using `grep` like this:

```
grep '^[abcd]*$' file.txt
```

I have a file, `list.txt`, containing a list like this:

```
potato
orange
carrot
```

How can I send all of the lines from `list.txt` to inside the search pattern of `grep`, the equivalent of typing this:

```
grep '^[potatoorangecarrot]*$' file.txt
```

All of the lines in `list.txt` are put together and sent to `grep` as one long search.

How can I place all of the text from a file into the search pattern of grep?

Comment: Not clear. What you are trying to achieve?

Comment: So you want find word of first file in second file right? If yes then use `grep -Fwf file1 file2`.

Comment: No, I just want to put the text from the `list.txt` into the search field in any kind of `grep` search. I just left one example. Maybe it is instead `grep '[allcontentsoffile]' file.txt`.

Comment: that doesn't make sense. You do know that `[abc]` is a "character class", right? It will match any one of `a`, `b` or `c` in any order. You wouldn't use this if you want to match the fixed string `abc`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
string="^[$(tr -d '\n' < list.txt)]*$"
echo $string
```

Then

```
grep "$string" file.txt
```

The `$()` bit says "*take the output of running the command within its parentheses*". The `tr` command says to delete (`-d`) all linefeeds from file `list.txt`.